# enter key as event in p:datatable jsf2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to select a row with the enter key in p:datatable using event?

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="l" selection="#{bean2.user}" rowKey="#{l}" selectionMode="single">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="@form"/>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{l.id}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! Check this sample code:

**The View**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:dataTable id="dt" value="#{rowSelectionBean.list}" var="item" 
                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{rowSelectionBean.selectedRow}"
                 widgetVar="dtVar" rowKey="#{item.id}">
        <p:column headerText="ID">
            #{item.id}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            #{item.name}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:outputPanel id="display">
        <h:outputText value="Selected row: #{rowSelectionBean.selectedRow.name}" rendered="#{not empty rowSelectionBean.selectedRow}" />
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:hotkey bind="return" update="display" process="dt" />
</h:form>
```

**The Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RowSelectionBean implements Serializable {

    private List<SimpleBean> list;

    private SimpleBean selectedRow;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        list = new ArrayList<SimpleBean>();
        list.add(new SimpleBean(11, "A"));
        list.add(new SimpleBean(22, "B"));
        list.add(new SimpleBean(33, "C"));
    }

    public SimpleBean getSelectedRow() {
        return selectedRow;
    }

    public void setSelectedRow(SimpleBean selectedRow) {
        this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
    }

    public List<SimpleBean> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? How exactly does the hotkey help the datatable make a selection and update the backing bean? I don't see any ajax tags anywhere on your table

Comment: Yes, I've tested it. If you want to see the ajax magic try it on this live demo: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf

Comment: Note that the hotkey component has ajax capabilities as well: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/hotkey.jsf

Comment: The example you linked has an actual `actionListener` or javascript action associated with the hotkey, yours doesn't. The ajax doesn't just happen; something has to send the value back. Since you've tested it however, it must be valid I guess.

Comment: I would not lie about that. You can trust me and primefaces on this one. The framework is so nice that it interprets the **update="display"** and **process="dt"** as a need for an ajax request. And if a datatable with **selectionMode="single"** and **selection="#{rowSelectionBean.selectedRow}"** has a row selected, primefaces assumes that you want to update the #{rowSelectionBean.selectedRow} with the value of the selected row.